# Message brooker for KEPServer EX 6

Tags: kepserverex

I am trying to figure out how to create a message broker for my tags in Kepware. Today I read them as is from the PLC. The problem is that sometimes I need logic for some tags. Say  for example a tag have Order-Date-Signature I would like to retrieve these as 3 different tags. This is what I can tell, not possible to do with Kepware. That means I would need a message broker.

What way should I go? My thought was to setup OPC UA server and read the information from one tag and write it to a simulator tag and then read those broker tags. Is this a good solution or should i go for something else? Basically I use  Siemens TCP/IP for reading and then sending it to the cloud with MQTT.